# Bullet positioning while rotating

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i'm creating an android app(top-down shooter) on libgdx and have a problem with bullet positioning(No, with math for real)
So the problem is calculating a position of bullet
I want to spawn bullet here:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WlUg.png)
(where the red line is)
I calculating a position as:

> bullet.setPosition(world.getPlayer().getX() + world.getPlayer().getWidth() * (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(world.getPlayer().getRotation())),
>                   world.getPlayer().getY() + world.getPlayer().getHeight()  * (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(world.getPlayer().getRotation())));

And it works well while rotation = 0, but as soon as i start to rotate my player it goes wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your player object is a libGDX `Sprite`. Therefore, the `getX` and `getY` are the coordinates of the bottom-left corner of the sprite and the `getRotation` is the rotation of the sprite about the origin (assumed to be at the centre of the player).

By doing some basic trigonometry you can convert the angle and a displacement to an (x,y) coordinate as you have attempted. The bullet needs to be rotated about the centre of the player. This can be done with the following code:

```
Sprite player = world.getPlayer(); //Just to tidy up the code

//Half width, half height and rotation
float hw = player.getWidth() / 2.0f;
float hh = player.getHeight() / 2.0f;
float rot = Math.toRadians(player.getRotation());

bullet.setPosition(player.getX() + hw + hw * (float) Math.cos(rot),
                   player.getY() + hh + hh * (float) Math.sin(rot));
```